# executor not executing threads from within a main thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a Thread which runs always with `while(true)` loop and basically all it does is to add Runnable objects to an executor.

OrderExecutionThread:

```
public class OrderExecutionThread extends Thread implements Runnable {
    final private static int ORDER_EXEC_THREADS_NUMBER = 10;
    private boolean running = true;
    private boolean flag = true;

    private List<Order> firstSellsList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Order> secondSellsList = new ArrayList<>();

    private ManagedDataSource managedDataSource;
    private ExecutorService executorService;

    public OrderExecutionThread(ManagedDataSource managedDataSource) {
        this.managedDataSource = managedDataSource;
        this.executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(ORDER_EXEC_THREADS_NUMBER);
    }

@Override
    public void run() {
        while (running) {
            if (!firstSellsList.isEmpty() && !firstBuysList.isEmpty()) {
                initAndRunExecution(firstBuysList.get(0), firstSellsList.get(0));
        }

    }

    private void initAndRunExecution(Order buy, Order sell) {
        executorService.submit(new OrderExecution(buy, sell, managedDataSource));
    }
}
```

I'm running this thread By doing this in my main class:

```
new Thread(orderExecutionThread).start();
```

The executor suppose to execute the `OrderExecution runnable` object which does this:

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            connection = managedDataSource.getConnection();
            makeExecution(sell, buy);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (!connection.isClosed())
                    connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

I know for sure that both lists are not empty and the `initAndRunExecution` is being called, however the order execution run method is not being called....

Comment: Try `firstBuysList.remove(0)` instead of `firstBuysList.get(0)`. Same for firstSells ... `get` does not remove the element. So you are in an endless loop submitting the same two elements in very high frequency. So I suspect your Executor-threads simply never get scheduled.

Comment: @Fildor, remove not working as well...

Comment: Oh, I see ok. Removed my comment. How do you fill those lists?

Comment: Ok, but what could be happen when firstSellsList.isEmpty() && firstBuysList.isEmpty(). Maybe is infinite loop here? And then `running` can be volatile, and can be change if loop must be stoped

Comment: Can you verify Tasks are actually being submitted? On second glance, you should be using Blocking Collections to avoid spin-wait. Spin-wait, where you actually do not wait. The App should put your CPU to 100% (or at least one core).

Comment: for starters add `else Thread.sleep(100);` - just for testing! Spin-wait is an Anti-Pattern.

Comment: In your `OrderExecutionThread` you have `secondSellsList` but don't have `firstBuysList`. Is it just a typo (instead of `secondSellsList`  in question's code snippet should be  `firstBuysList`) ? Or you have `firstBuysList` outside of this block of code, but visible in `OrderExecutionThread`?

Comment: Do you really close the DB connection every time or is it just a wrapper that puts the connection back to a pool?

Comment: Is that your [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? My feeling is it may be possible to demonstrate the same problem in fewer lines of code.

Comment: OK,  sleep fixed it.. Can someone please explain to me why the executor does not running the threads when I don't sleep

Comment: It's because you won't give up the CPU. Your main thread is so gready, that it doesn't allow other threads to be scheduled and executed. Thread.sleep forces the main thread to "pause", so others can work. But as I said: You should not stick to this solution. It just verifies my suspicion. Use blocking collections. They have for example `take` - that will block until an element is there to be consumed. Blocking allows to wait without spin-wait and it allows the VM to schedule other threads while waiting.

Comment: OK thanks,  I'll read about blocking collections

Comment: You could start here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html

Comment: It is doubtful that the solution was because of thread starvation @Fildor.  Most native thread implementations make this a non-issue.

Comment: @Gray Yes, that's right. Rethinking this, your suggestion seems more plausible. I guess a sleep just somehow leads to the main thread finally seeing the data update. I was drawing the wrong conclusions.

Comment: Exactly right @Fildor.

Answer (score 1):

> I know for sure that both lists are not empty and the initAndRunExecution is being called, however the order execution run method is not being called....

I suspect that this is a problem because your `firstSellsList` and `firstBuysList` are not synchronized collections.  I suspect that other threads are adding to those lists but your `OrderExecutionThread` never sees the memory updates so just spins forever seeing empty lists.  Whenever you share data between threads you need to worry about how the updates will be published and how the thread cache memory will be updated.

As @Fildor mentions in the comments, one solution would be to use a `BlockingQueue`s instead of your `List`s.   The `BlockQueue` (for example `LinkedBlockingQueue`) is a synchronized class so this takes care of the memory sharing.  An alternative benefit is that you don't have to do a spin-loop to watch for entries.

For example, your `OrderExecutionThread` might do something like:

```
private final BlockingQueue<Order> firstBuys = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
private final BlockingQueue<Order> firstSells = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
    // wait until we get a buy
    Order buy = firstBuys.take();
    // wait until we get a sell
    Order sell = firstSells.take();
    initAndRunExecution(buy, sell);
}
```

This will wait until the lists get entries before running the orders.